# In the evaporation process, will the temperature of both liquid and vapor molecules decrease?

Tags: temperature, phase-transition, gas, evaporation, liquid-state

The theory says that the molecules that become vapor "take" some energy from the surrounding molecules (the latent heat of evaporation). As a consequence, the temperature of the liquid falls a bit.
I'm wondering, will be the temperature of the vapors will be the same as that of the liquid phase ***before or after*** the detachment of the vapors? It will be higher than the temperature of the liquid? Or it will be the same?
From the thermodynamic point of view, is it possible that the vapors had a higher temperature at the moment of the detachment? But the liquid and vapors were in contact, so there should have been some heat transfer between them, which would have lead to the equalization of temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering, will be the temperature of the vapors will be the same
>   as that of the liquid phase before or after the detachment of the
>   vapors? It will be higher than the temperature of the liquid? Or it
>   will be the same?

The reason for evaporation in the first place is that the velocities, and thus kinetic energies, of some of the molecules of the liquid are greater than the average and some are less than the average. If some of the molecules at the surface of the liquid have kinetic energies great enough for them to overcome the intermolecular bonds they would be able to escape the liquid.

It stands to reason that, collectively, the molecules that escape together have a temperature greater than the temperature of the liquid, which is based on the lower overall average kinetic energy of the molecules in the liquid phase.

So to answer your question, the evaporating molecules would collectively theoretically have a temperature greater than the liquid. But it would be the vapor that is extremely close to the surface and would last very briefly. Assuming the bulk liquid temperature is the same as the air, then once evaporation occurs there will immediately be heat transfer from the vapor above the liquid  to the air.

Hope this helps.